# How to await fs.createReadStrem?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, fs

I have this code

```
router.post("/uploads", multer(multerConfig).single('file'), async (req, res) => {

// SOME CODE
count = 0;

try { 
    let connection
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig.dbAlarm);

    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
        .pipe(parse({
          delimiter: [';'],
          }), 
          column: true,
          bom: true, 
          trim: true
        })
      ).on('data', function(csvrow) {
          count = count + 1;
          console.log(count);
          })
       .on('end', async function() {
        // SOME CODE TO SELECT AND INSERT IN DATABASE
        })
       .on('close', () => {
          fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            console.log("File is deleted.");
          });
        });

    res.status(200).json({rows: count})
```

The problem is, in my response I always get 0. In my console.log(count) I can see perfectly all rows of my csv. How can I get the real number of rows? How can I "await" the fs?

Comment: Use `pipeline()` instead of `.pipe()` and then you can await the whole operation.  See the example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback).

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor and use a [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) as mentioned in the comments, but if you just want to await your current process, you could also just wrap it in a promise. Something like this should work for you:

```
try { 
    let connection
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig.dbAlarm);

    let count = await insertFileIntoDB(filePath)

    res.status(200).json({rows: count})
}

    
function insertFileIntoDB(filePath){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let count = 0
        fs.createReadStream(filePath)
        .pipe(parse({
          delimiter: [';'],
          }), 
          column: true,
          bom: true, 
          trim: true
        })
      ).on('data', function(csvrow) {
          count = count + 1;
          console.log(count);
          })
       .on('end', async function() {
        // SOME CODE TO SELECT AND INSERT IN DATABASE
        })
       .on('close', () => {
          fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
            console.log("File is deleted.");
            resolve(count)
          });
        });
        
        
    })
}
```